# Overriding the default formfield of a foreign key differently in add and change form in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm using formfield_for_foreignkey method on a ModelAdmin to override the default formfield for a foreign key. Its working perfectly. Is there any possibility to override formfield differntly for add and change forms??

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "idea":
        editor_group = Group.objects.filter(id=2).first()
        editors = AuthUser.objects.filter(groups=editor_group)
        if editors:
            f = FeaturedIdea.objects.all().values_list('idea__id', flat=True)
            kwargs["queryset"] = Idea.objects.filter(creator__in=editors).exclude(id__in=f)
        else:
            kwargs["queryset"] = Idea.objects.none()
    return super(FeaturedIdeaAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

my FeaturedIdea model is :

```
class FeaturedIdea(models.Model):

""" Model to create featured ideas """

idea = models.ForeignKey(Idea)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

On change form of FeaturedIdea I want to show the current featured idea too.

Comment: Please can you show what your `formfield_for_foreignkey` method is, and explain how you want it to change depending on whether it is the add/change form?